# Simple way to configure NodeJS environment

Tags: node.js

I am really just getting into cloud stuff and have been creating Node JS apps as a hobby for a long time. I am using MongoDB as my database. I have now pushed my app on Heroku and am happy that it runs, but I've only realized some things like there is no local storage and no database without addons. So now I have a free Atlas (MongoDB) hosting so my Heroku app can use that as its database.

My app starts with a simple `npm start` which does the build stuff (like grunt) and then runs the node app. But how can I change the environment to be production vs deploy so that if I did something like `npm start -prod` it would use the cloud hosted database, but `npm start -dev` would use my PC's MongoDB instance?

Comment: In nodejs environment variables are a common practise to use. Here is a good explanation how to use them. https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786

Answer (score 0):

This what I do -

Loading environment variables from an .env file and passing them to the Node.js runtime would be the ideal case.

```
const loadEnvironment = async function () {
  fs.readFile('.env', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    return (data);
  });
}; //loadEnvironment
```

For instance, file name .env which contains 'prod' or 'dev'. Handle db connections based on the env obtain from this file.